# Indexing of pdf and word docs with Plone4 and Windows

Tags: pdf, indexing, module, ms-word, plone

I followed an instruction for indexing pdf on Plone(4) (and Windows 2008) , that was originaly written for Plone3:

http://plone.org/documentation/kb/enable-indexing-of-pdf-and-word-docs-with-windows-in-five-steps-occurs-three-minutes-without-problems

I got an error on he fiths step "Add Transform; Enter in ID: pdf_to_text", when I tried to add the Module: Products.PortalTransforms.transforms.pdf_to_text.

Here is the Report:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 127, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 47, in call_object
  Module Products.PortalTransforms.TransformEngine, line 487, in manage_addTransform
  Module Products.PortalTransforms.TransformEngine, line 254, in _mapTransform
  Module Products.MimetypesRegistry.MimeTypesRegistry, line 220, in lookup
   - __traceback_info__: ("'BROKEN'", 'BROKEN')
  Module Products.MimetypesRegistry.MimeTypesRegistry, line 457, in split
MimeTypeException: Malformed MIME type (BROKEN)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, that *is* very old.

On Windows, the word indexing "Just Works" in Plone 4 if you have MS Office installed.  PDF still needs xpdf.

Is pdftotext.exe on your PATH?  It won't work if it isn't.  Remember, if you have added it to the system-wide environment, you are still going to have to stop/start Zope to have the Zope process pick up the changed PATH: run Zope in the foreground, from a command window that you **know** has pdftotext on the path, and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you! But I think it was not a problem of the Path, because I copied pdftotext.exe to C:\windows\system32. I can start it from command window on every place and it is working. Restarting the Plone instance had no effect. My windows is 64bit. I found a similar problem in another forum: http://plone.fr/support/forums/forum-utilisateurs/62341841

Comment: Nevertheless, it almost always **is** a problem with finding or running the executable, so do as I suggested and run in the foreground.  It's almost 100% guaranteed that you will see the error.

Comment: The challenge is not about getting the system to see it, nor the system level Python,  but the Python interpreter that runs Plone. The installer usually supplies its own.   

Starting Plone in the foreground will probably reveal the error. I am sorry that i don't know how to do this on Windows.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm not sure, if it was right, but I could start Plone from the command window with 'instance fg'. It showed the same error message as I already quoted. Only the first lines are different: "2011-04-28 10:46:08 ERROR PortalTransforms Cannot register transform pdf_to_text
 (ImportError), using BrokenTransform: Error
 No module named pdf_to_text
2011-04-28 10:46:08 ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog 1303980368.090.283088051811 http://192.168.1.55/portal_transforms/manage_addTransform

Comment: @Jochen Sorry I forgot about this - and SO doesn't email me to remind.  In "instance debug", try: `from Products.PortalTransforms import transforms`, then try `dir(transforms)` and see if pdf_to_text even shows up